# jQuery slide doesn't work correctly in Chrome, but is fine on Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css

I added a jQuery transitional slideshow to my webpage using WOWSlider. It works fine on Firefox. However on Google Chrome, when the image changes to the next, it flickers and doesn't run smoothly. Could anyone help me as to why this is? Thank you! Much appreciated!

http://zeendesign.co.uk/smiledental.co.uk/SmileDental/SmileDental/

Comment: paste related code here, or this quetion is useless fro comunity

Comment: You probably will not find an answer without showing any of the code, I tried to look at the js but it's minified.

Also, I can not re-create the problem. It works fine on Mac Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It's working on my Chrome, the latest: 24.0.1312.57